# Protected property setter on .aspx not working

Tags: properties, user-controls, webforms, protected

Could any body explain why if I have protected property in control it couldn't be set from .aspx?

Control:

```
public partial class SomeUserControl : UserControl
{
    protected bool SomeProperty
    {
        get { return ViewState["SomeProperty"] != null && (bool) ViewState["SomeProperty"]; }
        set { ViewState["SomeProperty"] = value; }
    }

    ...
}
```

Declaration in .aspx:

```
<custom:SomeUserControl ID="SomeUserControl1" runat="server" SomeProperty="true"/>
```

When I am trying to debug setter never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just realized that it wasn't visible with intellisense. And this property recognized like as HTML attribute.